# Why does the A-320 allow 1.3 degrees more left rudder trim than right?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a320

On the a320, can someone explain why this is:

> AMM 27-22-00 PB 001
>   NOTE:The maximum admissible rudder trim limits
>   indicated on the control panel when the aircraft is stabilized in
>   heading with the AP engaged are RH 1 DEG and LH 2.3 DEG.

Why is there a 1.3 difference in deg between LH & RH?

Answer (score 5):

Both engines turn the same way, and the bypass fans exert torque in order to accelerate the air passing through them. The torque needs to be trimmed out using aileron & rudder trim.

Comment: This is really interesting. It seems difficult for the pilot. Why don't the engines turn in opposite directions?

Comment: @BrianGordon: that would require two mostly different engines. Twice as much spare engines, higher production costs, and so on. Though, many propeller driven aircraft, where the torque plays a bigger role, have counter-rotating engines/propellers.

Comment: Also, it's easier to reverse the direction of a turboprop where you've already got a gearbox before the propeller. Turbofans generally have the fan on the same shaft as the low-pressure compressor and turbine, so you would need to rebuild half the core to change direction.

Comment: @BrianGordon it's not really a problem for the pilot when the designers have compensated for it, for example, by allowing more left rudder trim than right.